# lotus notes: error message when accessing a view

Tags: view, lotus-notes

Our users told us that when they accessed some views from an outline this prompt  - message is showing:

```
Not a member: ALLDOCUMENTS
```

After this message is shown, the view is opened correctly. I opened the respective views but in the view selection formula there isn't any `@Formula` regarding `@UserRoles`.

Also, in designer when I modify something and then ctrl + S the view => same error, with the title of the prompt message: IBM Domino Designer.

I appreciate any help and your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means, that somewhere in the code of the view that is being opened there is LotusScript- Code, that tries to call the "allDocuments"- Property of an object. "AllDocuments" usually is a member of NotesDatabase- Class. But maybe a developer mixed it up with the "AllEntries"- Property of the NotesView- Class. Or the NotesDatabase- Object is defined as Variant and not assigned yet (timing issue)...

Whatever: This is a selfmade error... Ask the developer of the app or find out yourself:

You need to use the designer- client to examine the view that should be opened for any LotusScript found there or use the Debugger to find out the faulting code.

Comment: There aren't any events of the view used, only View Selection. There are some action buttons which contain LotusScript. Should I look the code inside the action buttons?

Comment: Also, in designer when I modify something and then ctrl + S => same error, with the title of the prompt message: IBM Domino Designer.

Comment: This IS a LotusScript Error Message. So there IS LotusScript- Code somewhere... And yes, this can be action buttons as well as Used LotusScript- Libraries, etc... Note: EVER use "Option Declare" in the globals of any element you code, then something like this can never be saved...

Comment: I did found:  Dim collectionFolder As notesdocumentCollection
 Dim folderDel As notesview
 Set folderDel = db.GetView ("TrashTrash")
 Set collectionFolder = folderDel.AllDocuments
 Call doc.RemoveFromFolder ("TrashTrash") .. and if I comment  the .AllDocuments line the error doesn't appear no longer...

Comment: This code is... Trash... Remove it or fix it... just commenting out the faulty line (as I thought: developer meant AllEntries and there is no Option declare) just makes it worse. If this code is meant to do something, then make it do what it should. If not -> trash it

Comment: Is there actually a view named "TrashTrash"? Or is it a typo?

Comment: @Richard: yes, there is a view named "TrashTrash".

Comment: In fact, it is a folder